# Apache Server does not update certificate for subdomains after restart

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpd

I have a server which has domain1.example.com and domain2.example.com. The server is using 2 certificates one for domain1.example.com and a UCC certificate for domaind.example.com. My ssl config is as follows

```
<VirtualHost ************:443>
    ServerName domain1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain1.example.com/scripts"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain1.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain1.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ************:443>
    ServerName domain2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain2.example.com/scripts"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain2.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain2.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Originally both domains were setup with the non UCC certificate. I restarted the apache server yet the domain2 still shown as insecure with the certificate of domain1. The server was both stop and started as we as restarted, so no graceful restart situation. Any hints as to what is not allowing the website to come up with the new certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the first non-UCC certificate was under the same CommonName as the UCC certificate. Simply using the UCC certificate on all the VirtualHosts sovled the issue.

Comment: Can you  mark your answer as valid ? thanks